# Voltmeter- Readings

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

What would the reading be on this voltmeter?

[image]

Suppose The battery is $5V$. Would the reading be $5V$? If you see it from the other way, the two ends of the voltmeter are connected by ideal wires; therefore, shouldn't the voltmeter reading be zero?

Comment: use https://www.circuitlab.com

Comment: You need a resistor somewhere in your circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Your battery seems to be short circuited. Therefore the voltage reading on your voltmeter is zero.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal battery which has no internal resistance, there is no answer to your question (you would have infinite currents in the circuit).

For a practical battery (non-ideal), there exists some internal resistance. The internal resistance can be modeled as follows:

[image]

The current through your circuit would be:

$$I = \frac{V}{r}$$

Therefore, the potential drop across the internal resistance would be:

$$V_{drop} = Ir = \frac{V}{r} r = V$$

The net potential difference across the battery is:

$$V_{net} = V - Ir = V - V = 0$$

This is consistent with KVL rule. The voltmeter will read $0V$.

Answer (score -1):

The reading will be 0 volt as voltmeter will read potential drop across battery but for potential drop their should be some electrical element as in given circuit there is no electrical element there is no potential drop and hence reading of voltmeter will be zero